# Photonic density of states?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, quantum-optics

Could someone explain intuitively what exactly is the photonic density of states? What are the main parameters that affect it? What is its role in nanophotonics?

Also, any good references/textbooks for learning more about this would be helpful. Thanks!